# SQL Query to join 3 tables with only two tables have common entity

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables : Table A , Table B and Table C.

```
Table A has 3 columns Column A,Column B,Column C
Table B has 3 columns Column A,Column D, Column E
Table C has 2 columns Column F , Column E
```

with Inner Join i was able to query on Table A and Table B and Table B and Table C but for my result to be solved I would require data by merging A and C as well.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well given the little info provided I'd say that it would be as simple as this:

```
SELECT A, B, C 
FROM A
JOIN B on A.A = B.A
JOIN C on B.E = C.E
```

Ofcourse if there are no matches on table B you wont get any on table C